# Is there a way in Liquid to use the contains operator to check for an exact match?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

When searching an array for a match in a Liquid template, how do you call `contains exactly`? For example, if tag of a page may contain `separable` or `non-separable`, how do you find the pages that contain only the `separable` and not the `non-separable` tag? In my experience, the `{% if post.tags contains 'separable' %}` statement considers both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the array and check the values with a match operator. If it matches change a variable from false to true:

```
{% assign found_seperable = false %}
{% for tag in post.tags %}
  {% if tag == 'separable' %}
    {% assign found_seperable = true %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then check the variable:

```
{% if found_seperable %}
  do what you want if true
{% else %}
  do what you want if false
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the *[documentation](https://www.siteleaf.com/blog/advanced-liquid-where/)* you can use this filter

```
{% assign tags = post.tags | where:"tag","separable" %}
```